# What anime movie is this?

Tags: expelled-from-paradise

I watched a scifi anime movie and I forgot its name. All I remember is the story and characters. I think the female robot protagonist was on the cover of the movie and had blue or white scifi style clothing. I also think the movie was made in 2014, but I'm not sure.

Story: The movie starts in a hologram environment where the female protagonist is sunbathing. Gets hit on by a guy when suddenly the hologram room gets hacked and she traces this hack to earth. Later on it is revealed that the hacker is an AI trying to get people on his rocket out of Earth to colonize new planets. The AI leaves himself without anyone else in the end of the movie.

Main protagonist: Female data. Lives in a big structure above earth in space. Is allowed additional "memory" due to high enthusiasm and goals. Gets a mission to go down to earth. She hastened the body creation and took the body of herself at the age of 18 instead of her grown-up body. She falls to earth in a pod meeting her informant (male) luring mutated beast animals to her on purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It's Rakuen Tsuihou: Expelled from Paradise, a 2014 movie. Genres: action, mecha, sci-fi.

Movie poster and the girl's "data":

[image] [image]

Description from [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/13391/Rakuen_Tsuihou:_Expelled_from_Paradise):

> With Earth now left in ruins following the "Nano Hazard," most of
>   humanity has abandoned the planet they once called home along with
>   their physical bodies and rebuilt their digitalized minds into a
>   society within the cyber universe of "DEVA."
>
> A.D. 2400, DEVA's central council detects an incident of unauthorized
>   access into their mainframe. Someone on Earth was trying to hack into
>   the system. The only information DEVA was able to retrieve was that
>   the hacker referred to themselves as "Frontier Setter."
>
> To investigate the mysterious hacker's motives, the high officials of
>   DEVA dispatch System Security Third Officer Angela Balzac to the
>   Earth's surface. Equipped with a prosthetic "material body," Angela
>   attempts to make contact with a local agent Dingo, but what awaited
>   her instead was a swarm of Sandworms now infesting the Earth's
>   surface. Angela intercepts the gruesome pests with her exoskeletal
>   powered suit Arhan.
>
> Will Angela and Dingo be able to find Frontier Setter on this
>   devastated planet?
>
> Their journey to explore the secrets of the world will begin now...!

Comment: Thank you, this movie left an impression on me and I have yet to find a scifi movie of this quality. Great quick answer. :P